# How can we sort the records of having duplicate records?

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a table as given below

```
 FirstName            SurName
    Himaja          V
    Himaja           K
   mahendar          Faye 
    Karthik                  Null
   Varun                    M
```

Now I want to sort this table so that the required output would be alphabetical order from A to Z same in the Surname also.

Can any one help me regarding this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`select * from table order by FirstName, SurName;`

You can add more than one column to the order clause. If the FirstName values are the same, then the rows are ordered by SurName.

Comment: But When I execute this Query FirstName is Sorted ,Surname is not sorted like alphabetical order

Comment: You cannot sort both of them in alphabetical order. You can sort only by one column. If two records have the same value in the sorted column, then they will be sorted using the second sort parameter and so on...

Comment: The query should return: Himaja/K, Himaja/V, Karthik/Null, mahendar/Faye, Varun/M. Is this what you want to achieve?

Comment: Yes :-) Is there any possibility to get the Second Column values also in Sorted Order?

Comment: No. You can sort only whole rows. You cannot mix values from different columns and put them in separate rows.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY FirstName, SurName
```

You cannot sort both of them in alphabetical order. You can sort only by one column. If two records have the same value in the sorted column, then they will be sorted using the second sort parameter and so on...

Here's nice example - how should you sort those names:

```
A B
C D
E A
F B
```

to keep the both columns sorted in alphabetical order?

Comment: Thanks for replying :-) But When I execute this Query FirstName is Sorted ,Surname is not sorted like alphabetical order